# seccomp system call priority values 65535

Tags: bpf, seccomp

I've read that priority can be a value between 0 and 255 (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/seccomp_syscall_priority.3.html). Why using seccomp_export_pfc the baseline priority is 65535???

```
 # filter for syscall "exit_group" (231) [priority: 65535]
  if ($syscall == 231)
    action ALLOW;
  # filter for syscall "exit" (60) [priority: 65535]
  if ($syscall == 60)
    action ALLOW;
```

Comment: Could you post the code you used to create this seccomp filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are two different things: with [`seccomp_syscall_priority`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/seccomp_syscall_priority.3.html), you provide a **priority hint**, whereas [`seccomp_export_pfc`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/seccomp_export_bpf.3.html) outputs [libseccomp's internal priority](https://github.com/seccomp/libseccomp/blob/70df5b32573772cf3d103b7523ee1be14c0251df/src/gen_pfc.c#L250-L251).

As explained in [the source code comments](https://github.com/seccomp/libseccomp/blob/78497a5d1da200ab0356e1189f5efb8724ad70a1/src/db.c#L41-L46), the internal priority contains your priority hint, if any, as the first 16 bits. The last 16 bits are useful is case of tie (i.e., two filters have the same upper 16 bits), in which case libseccomp gives higher priority to filters that are easier to evaluate.

So, in your case, since you did not provide any hint, [the internal priority is equal to `0x0000FFFF`](https://github.com/seccomp/libseccomp/blob/78497a5d1da200ab0356e1189f5efb8724ad70a1/src/db.c#L2033), or 65535.

Comment: Thanks, what does "in case of tie" mean?

Comment: In case two filters have the same priority hint. I'll edit the post for clarity.

Comment: So anyway in the computation of the priority it's also subtracted the number of nodes (does this mean how many "branches" has the filter?)

Comment: If I understand correctly libseccomp's code, they represent filters internally as graphs before generating the bytecode. So the number of nodes would be the number of code blocks in the control flow graph of your program. It's just one way to measure the complexity of a piece of code.